# How to get color of pixel at mouse position?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app in R and I'm trying to have it update based a color selected by mouse click/hover in the app.

I have a swatch of colors, and if they click on one of the colors, I want the app to update based on that input. To that end, I'm  trying to get the color info of the pixel from that mouse input.

To be clear, I don't want a color selection widget where people manually select some other way.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You mean the color of a pixel on an image ? (rendered with `plotOutput`)

Comment: Ultimately, I think you'll have to get the position of the mouse and then translate it to a color. How you do the translation will depend on how you are rendering the swatch. Is it in a static image? Is it a shiny rendered object that has reactive sources defined? Is it an html table?

Comment: The swatch is a barplot using renderPlot() in shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var getPixelColor = setInterval(function(){
    var $img = $("#ggplot>img");
    if($img.length){
      clearInterval(getPixelColor);
      var img = $img[0];
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
      $img.on("click", function(e){
        var pixelData = canvas.getContext("2d").
          getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
        Shiny.setInputValue("color", Array.prototype.slice.call(pixelData));
      })
    }
  }, 100);
})
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 9,
      plotOutput("ggplot")
    ),
    column(
      width = 3,
      h3("pixel RGBA:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("pixelRGBA"),
      br(),
      h3("pixel color:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("pixelColor")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris) + 
      geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species), 
                 size = 3)
  })

  output[["pixelRGBA"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["color"]]
  })

  pixelColor <- reactive({
    req(input[["color"]])
    rgba <- input[["color"]]
    rgb(rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3], rgba[4], maxColorValue = 255)
  })

  output[["pixelColor"]] <- renderPrint({
    pixelColor()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you! I was able to slot in my own plot into 
 output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({...

and it did exactly what I needed. Thanks again.